# AngularJS Reference Errors

Tags: angularjs

I'm getting some error messages when I try to run my app.  I'm not sure what they mean.  I'm getting the error Uncaught ReferenceError: accountInfoController is not defined and Uncaught ReferenceError: accountInfoService is not defined.

This is my controller:

```
(function () {

'use strict';

angular
  .module('crm.ma')
  .controller('accountInfoController', accountInfoController);

accountInfoController.$inject = ['accountInfoService', 'toastr', '$scope'];

function getAccountInfo() {
    accountInfoService.getAccountInfo().then(function (response) {
        if (response.error) {
            toastr.error(response.error);
        }
        else {
            vm.details = response;
        }
    })       
}  
}());
```

here's my service

```
(function () {

angular
.module('crm.ma')
.service('accountInfoService', accountInfoService);

accountInfoService.$inject = ['$http', 'apiUrl'];


function getAccountInfo() {
    return $http.get(apiUrl + 'GetAccountDetails')
    .then(function (response) {
        return response.data;
    }, function (response) {
        return { error: response.data.message }
    });
}
}());
```

Does it have something to do with my router?

```
    .state('index.DetailsTest', {
             url: '/details',
             templateUrl: 'app/components/main/account/account-details/DetailsTest.html',
             controller: 'accountInfoController',
             data: {
                 pageTitle: 'Test'
             }

         })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you haven't actually defined the functions for your controller `accountInfoController` and `accountInfoService`.  You've just defined the methods that should be inside the controller and service

Your code for your controller should look something like:

```
(function () {

'use strict';

angular
  .module('crm.ma')
  .controller('accountInfoController', accountInfoController);

accountInfoController.$inject = ['accountInfoService', 'toastr', '$scope'];
function accountInfoController(accountInfoService, toastr, $scope) {

  var vm = this;
  vm.getAccountInfo = getAccountInfo
  function getAccountInfo() {
    accountInfoService.getAccountInfo().then(function (response) {
        if (response.error) {
            toastr.error(response.error);
        }
        else {
            vm.details = response;
        }
    })       
  }  

}
}());
```

and something similar for your service

Comment: Hi Peter Elliott.  Thank you for your help.  My controller works perfectly now.  I'm not sure how the service should be though?

Comment: same thing, wrap the service in a function named ``accountInfoService``

Comment: Ok!  I think I got it.  Thanks for your help.  Now to figure out the next error message.  :)